# Espresso AmbiguousViewMatcherException when trying to click a switch frame

Tags: android, exception, android-espresso, android-testing

when i try to run below test, i got AmbiguousViewMatcherException, how can i get expected view from multiple views.

```
   ViewInteraction switch_ = onView(
            allOf(withClassName(is("android.widget.Switch"))
                    childAtPosition(
                            allOf(withId(android.R.id.widget_frame),
                                    childAtPosition(
                                            withClassName(is("android.widget.LinearLayout")),
                                            2)),
                            0),
                    isDisplayed()));
    switch_.perform(click());
```

It gives me the following exception with two switch id matching

```
Switch{id=16909051, res-name=switchWidget, visibility=VISIBLE, width=136, height=51, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=6.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false} ****MATCHES**


Switch{id=16909051, res-name=switchWidget, visibility=VISIBLE, width=136, height=51, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=6.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false} ****MATCHES****
```

I have tried using hasfocus(), withEffectiveVisibility(VISIBLE) methods but unable to solve the problem.

Can someone help here?

Comment: Could you add the view hierarchy?

Comment: Hi @nenick thanks for responding. I figured out a solution for this and it works fine. Defining a View matcher method based on index worked for me:

Comment: @nenick posted my code in the answer for everyone's reference

Answer (score 0):

The following method solved my issue.

The multiple views with same id are now accessed using the index method.

```
 public static Matcher<View> withIndex(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int index) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with index: ");
            description.appendValue(index);
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            return matcher.matches(view) && currentIndex ++== index;
        }
    };
}
```

after defining the method just added this line to the test case for accessing the correct switch frame

```
onView(withIndex(withId(android.R.id.widget_frame), 3)).perform(click());
```